# pandoc could not create internal links while converting md to html

Tags: html, pandoc

I am not able to create table of contents or internal links using 'pandoc' when converting markdown file to html file?

Comment: What's the input? Which command are you using?

Comment: Input is sample.md file                                                                                                            
                                                                                          
 And the command is  pandoc --toc sample.md -o sample.html                           But it is working for md to pdf.

Comment: well... what's the contents of `sample.md`? see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Also make sure that you're using the newest pandoc version.

Comment: @prajna you'll need to add `--standalone` to your command. PDFs are always standalone, which is why it works there.